# How do I get an onEdit script to run on a Google Spreadsheet for all users

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I created an onEdit script which re-sorts a Google Spreadsheet every time a cell is edited.

The Google Spreadsheet is shared amongst multiple users and I'd like the script to run for all users, every time the spreadsheet is opened.

How do I set this up?

Comment: You must use the on open function first, and call for the sort function.

Comment: See following answer I gave: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/36352/29140

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that a bug in my script was stopping it from running. For anyone who stumbles across this question trying to solve a similar problem here is my working script:

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var tableRange = "A2:F999";

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == 6){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort([{column: 6}, {column: 4}, {column: 5}]);
  }
}
```